# window.history.pushState back button working, but not forward once clicked back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, model-view-controller

```
function processAjaxData(response, urlPath) {
window.history.pushState({}, '', '/user/index2');
$(window).bind('popstate', function () {
    window.location.href = window.location.href;
});
```

Above is the function i'm using , once ajax response is true from controller . i get data as HTML and i dump it into body . then calls the above function, i change the URL

Everything works fine, once click back button i can go to Index1 (localhost/user/index1), page but then from Index1 page i click forward browser button , HTML wont update only URL changes to localhost/user/index2

Comment: Show the part of the code that updates the HTML. `window.location.href = window.location.href` in your popstate event handler doesn't do anything.

Comment: @MikaelLennholm : [link]https://jsfiddle.net/51r3qvmb/
So i have two pages Index1 and Index 2 ,  on load Index1 page loads and i have a button on Index 1 page when clicked in button i load Index 2 using Ajax and partial view from MVC controller. so once ajax success calls i dump the HTML in body .and then i change URL and use above function processAjaxData();
So help me navigate using back and forward button . when click back button user should go to Index1 and when clicked forward he should go to Index2 .